# Redeploying phonegap app for ios after phonegap update

Tags: ios, xml, cordova

I am trying to redeploy a app that have been made using phonegap.

I am a noob as fast as phonegap goes, I have updated the app, and it is working on android and local mashine. I am able to build the app for ios using build.phonegap. But when I try to deliver the app to Apple appstore I get a couple of errors: 
ERROR ITMS-90478: "Invalid Version. The build with the version "708" can't be imported because a later version has been closed for new build submissions. Choose a different version number."
ERROR ITMS-90062: "This build is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString[1.0.9] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previous approved version[708]."

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="dk.energi2020.appv2" version="1.0.9">   <name>Energy Tour</name>   <description>Energy tours guides you to exciting places</description>   <author href="http://www.energi2020.dk" email="post@rksk.dk">Ringkøbing - Skjern Kommune</author>   <content src="index.html"/>   <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>   <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1"/>   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0"/>   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0"/>
     <icon src="icon.png"/>   <platform name="android">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon_ldpi.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon_mdpi.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon_hdpi.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon_xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon_xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon_xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>   </platform>   <platform name="ios">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" platform="ios" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" platform="ios" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" platform="ios" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" platform="ios" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" platform="ios" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" platform="ios" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" platform="ios" width="58" height="58"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>   </platform>   <access origin="*"/>   <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>   <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/> </widget>
```

I am only able to find one plist file and it looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>dk.energi2020.appv2</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1009</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1009</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key>
    <string/>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Could anybody help me figure this one out?

Comment: downgrade the version of ios that will solve your problem.

Comment: How do i do that?